# Make tests dependent and fail together in googletest?

Tags: googletest

In googletest, is there a way to make tests dependent on each other? I have one test (a database connection) for which if it fails, it doesn't make sense to run certain other tests (that use the DB). I'd like to make those dependent tests fail fast without executing.

I could put the assertion of the DB connection test into a test fixture, but since a new fixture object is constructed for every test, it will run a lot of times unnecessarily. Is there an elegant way to make all the DB using tests fail together?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [a googletest Environment](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/AdvancedGuide#Global_Set-Up_and_Tear-Down) to create the DB connection.

Or I guess you could set a global boolean when the test successfully makes the DB connection, and which is checked at the start of every other test.